# How to copy text from another application to emacs in ubuntu?

Tags: copy-paste

I am using emacs 23.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am having problems trying to copy text from another application (most of the time, Firefox) to emacs. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to isolate when you can copy text successfully, and when you cannot.

Comment: How do you usually try to copy and paste..? Are you using a keyboard shortcut? Do you highlight + Middle-click paste? Are you pasting into a terminal?

Comment: From my experience, GUI Emacs just works with the clipboard without any configuration. I think I've tried it on Ubuntu too. Just make sure you're using the correct keyboard shortcuts. In most programs `C-c` copies and `C-v` pastes, but in Emacs it's `M-w` and `C-y`respectively.

Comment: I would like to mention that currently there is no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have that in my configuration :

```
(setq select-enable-primary nil)
(setq select-enable-clipboard t)
```

on my side it works for gnome-shell (I didn't try with unity)

Comment: I guess I neglected to mention that I am completely new to both emacs and linux. Do I have to add this code to the .emacs file?

Comment: yes you should had the code in the .emacs file but I just realize that this variables are obsolete since emacs 25.1, I updated the previous comment in consequence

Answer (score 0):

This should use the system clipboard:

```
(defun copy-from-ubuntu (text &optional push)
  (interactive)
  (if (display-graphic-p)
      (progn
        (message "Yanked region to x-clipboard!")
        (call-interactively 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
        )
    (if (region-active-p)
        (progn
          (shell-command-on-region (region-beginning) (region-end) "xsel -i -b")
          (message "Yanked region to clipboard!")
          (deactivate-mark))
      (message "No region active; can't yank to clipboard!")))
    )

(defun paste-to-ubuntu ()
  (interactive)
  (if (display-graphic-p)
      (progn
        (clipboard-yank)
        (message "graphics active")
        )
    (insert (shell-command-to-string "xsel -o -b"))
    )
  )
```

And then finally add:

```
(setq interprogram-cut-function 'copy-from-ubuntu)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'paste-to-ubuntu)
```

You will also need to install `xsel`

```
$ sudo apt-get install xsel
```

Comment: I guess I neglected to mention that I am completely new to both emacs and linux. Do I have to add this code to the .emacs file?

Comment: Yes, just add the two defuns and two setq to your .emacs (or init.el) file.
The "sudo apt-get install xsel" command you must run in the terminal application.